# What cable do I need to connect this motherboard DVD port to this DVD drive?

Tags: motherboard, sata, dvd, cable, cd

This is an image of my laptop motherboard DVD drive connector. Seems to be 13 pins:

[image]

And this is another image of the connector to an internal laptop DVD drive I have (one that doesn't physically fit into my laptop). Seems to be 25 pins:

[image]

**QUESTION:** What cable do I need to buy to connect the two together? Are both ports SATA ports? I don't know anything about hardware.

**UPDATE with more information:**

- Don't see any model number on the motherboard. Laptop: Acer Extensa, model **MS2394**
- DVD drive is from Sony, model number: **CRX880A**

By the way, I should mention that the laptop didn't ship with any DVD drive in it, but it seems pretty obvious opening up the laptop that it has an unused connector that I could use for connecting a DVD drive. They just put a hunk of removable plastic instead of a DVD drive, presumably to keep the laptop as cheap as possible (it's a low-end laptop).

Comment: It would help if you [edit] your question to provide the make/model number of both your motherboard and your DVD drive ...

Comment: @HardwareIgnoramus  - Please take the time to provide the specifics we have requested.  You just edited your question.  If you want an answer this really is required for us to help.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, more info posted. does this help?

Comment: How old is this laptop?  I can't find any evidence it exists on the web.

Comment: @Ramhound It's actually a very new laptop. I bought it only a few months ago. It shipped with Windows 8 or 8.1.

Comment: @HardwareIgnoramus - Product website with specifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t use this DVD drive in your laptop. The drive has an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA) connector, while the laptop has a newer [SATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA) port.

Here is a [link](http://www.sony-optiarc.us/endoflifeproducts/dvddrives/slim/combo/crx880a.html) to your DVD drive.  It has a Parallel ATA interface while the laptop has a Serial ATA interface.  They are not electrically compatible.

Comment: Hey, the drive doesn't have to go into the laptop itself. I don't mind a cable connecting the two and the drive remaining outside the physical laptop itself (the cable would just go through the opening of the laptop). Is there such an IDE to SATA cable?

Comment: @HardwareIgnoramus No! They are two incompatible interfaces.

Comment: Thanks, your great wisdom astounds me. Can you mention a cheap DVD/CD drive + cable on eBay that I can connect to the motherboard SATA port with a cable? Again, the drive doesn't have to fit into the laptop itself, it can be outside of it. An ugly setup, but it works for me. (Although bonus points if it fits into the laptop! Of course harder to find I guess)

Comment: @HardwareIgnoramus, if you turn your workaround into hardware shopping recomendation you are falling down into off-topic darkness.

Comment: @HardwareIgnoramus: They sell converters that would let you interface the two, but you would end up with a kluge of the convertor and connector adapters, and it probably wouldn't have the performance of just using the right type of drive (and you wouldn't save much by the time you were done).

Comment: Now I'm getting confused. As I mentioned in my last comment, I'm willing to discard the DVD drive mentioned in my question and obtain a new DVD drive that would work with the laptop motherboard. That's all. Surely such a DVD drive exist --- along with a cable to connect the two in the very likely case that the new DVD drive doesn't fit into the actual laptop. I just need your help locating such a drive and such a cable. Thanks for looking into this so far guys. Appreciated.

Comment: @HardwareIgnoramus: Yes, buy a new DVD drive.  You can probably find one that will fit inside your laptop if it has an empty bay.  I couldn't find your laptop on the Acer site, and little mention of it in a search.  The only thing I found was this link to a Mexican retailer showing a Liteon DVD drive: http://articulo.mercadolibre.com.mx/MLM-512259873-laptop-acer-modelo-ms2394-2-gb-en-ram-500-gb-_JM.  It's a place to start in your information search.  BTW, you're famous: http://serverquestions.com/questions/jq6e/what-cable-do-i-need-to-connect-this-motherboard-dvd-port-to-this-dvd-drive

Answer (score 0):

**Slim ATAPI to Mini Sata??** but i have never seen one as this in the normal stores, maybe you miss a propietary piece of hardware(an adapter)[if the DVD is the original] or instead a compatible Optical Hardware.

I suggest you to ask about the spare code about the compatible hardware with Acer support and compare with your current device.

*There is an referencial image about what im talking about.*

[image]

Comment: I knew the bottom was ATA just could figure out why it don't have more pins, it's because, it's slim/micro :$